# WPF clicked button returns null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I don't know why my clicked buttons returns Null.

Here's my XAML:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.New" Executed="NewCommand_Execute" CanExecute="NewCommand_CanExecute"></CommandBinding>
</Window.CommandBindings>

<Grid Name="GridTypuZasilan">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Name="Btn" Height="40"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Name="ItemControlTypZasilania" ItemsSource="{Binding TypyZasilania}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <Expander Name="TypZasilaniaExp" Header="{Binding expHeader}" >
                    <Border Margin="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <DataGrid Tag="{Binding dgTag}" Margin="5" CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="0">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Towar" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Ilość" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            </DataGrid>

                            **<Button Name="BtnName" Tag="{Binding btnTag}" Content="Add something" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="ApplicationCommands.New" ></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </Button>**

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Expander>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

This is the command I'm using:

```
private void NewCommand_Execute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender as Button != null)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show((sender as Button).Tag.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Null");
    }
}
```

and code that builds the view:

```
TypyZasilania = new ObservableCollection<TypyZasilan.typZasilania>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    TypZasilania = new TypyZasilan.typZasilania() { expHeader = "Expander_" + i, btnTag = "btn_TypZasilania_" + i, dgTag = "dg_TypZasilania_" + i };
    TypyZasilania.Add(TypZasilania);
}

GridTypuZasilan.DataContext = this;
```

My window look like:

[image: App]

When I iterate over the buttons in DataGrid, it looks like there are 2 times more than it should be and half of them return null.

Can you explain why it is null and how I can get clicked button properties?

Comment: Why do you need a button info in your viewmodel??

Comment: @Ugur, Frist, Thank you for your interest. 
I need to know which button i pressed to use it to add data, to appropriate DataGrid. When i get clicked button Tag i can compare it with DataGrid Tag 
and I will know where to enter the data.

Or maybe it is a bad way and it's better solution.. 
This is the first thing I thought about. Im new in mvvm and in general in wpf.

Comment: I guess you should change your design. Focused on selected object in data grid. Try to bind selected object to viewmodel. For example, you can remove this "AddButton" under data grid. Regarding on selected object, you can even set button disable or enable. If it is already enable, user can add something ...

Comment: Give a time to learn commands and bindings, refer more on datagrid. There should be no view elements on viewmodel side

Comment: Try to use command without triggers:<Button  Command="ApplicationCommands.New" ....